# Window comparator with transient detection

Tags: comparator, transient, multivibrator, range-detector

[image]
I need some advice with over range circuitry I my design. In summary, I need to probe two nodes in my circuit and raise an alarm if any of them raises above approx. 2V peak (in both polarities). The Schematic in the picture shows partial implementation. It is a window comparator with +2 V -2V. I intended to use open-collector however I got LT1716 instead I believe they are compatible. With a low pass filter added to the LED design works well for DC and signals with a large duty cycle. I am worried about transient states.

1. I would like the output to “latch” for a second or more anytime a transient state with peak amplitude above 2V occurs. I currently use a monostable multivibrator to achieve this.
2. Relatch if a second transient even occurs while the output is still in a latched state. I currently use LT6993 with some circuitry to achieve this.

However, due to the complexity and cost of LT6993, I would like to mimic this behaviour using cheaper components.

Comment: Is it not interresting to replace LT6993 by a programmable component as a Digispark ATTiny85 or other ? Just changing the output to be between -0.7V and 5V.

Comment: Introducing MCU requires separate Analogue and digital ground as the clock switching of ATTiny85 would degrade the analogue performance. Additionally, all devices with a clock above 9KHz require more strict EMC regulations. Also, the cost is not much cheaper than LT6993.

Comment: ok, valuable reason. What are the objectives or constraints ?

Comment: An idea ... Clocking DigiSpark at 1 kHz ? Or another up :)

Comment: Minimum software effort.
No digital ground plane due to increased PCB complexity and cost.
Low cost.
Ideally based on few passives and active components.

Comment: Clocking MCU at 1KHz even if ADC completed the conversion in one clock cycle would be too slow to detect the fast-changing transient states. Even at the maximum allowed 9KHz if MCU would complete a full ADC conversion it would still be too slow to detect transients. 
Additionally, introducing MCU and developing software would be an overkill in terms of resources and cost compared to LT6993.